# HTML escape not working in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, html, adderror

I am adding an error message to a record using the Sobject.addError(errorMsg, escape) method, and I am trying to add a clickable link to my customer service departments phone number.

```
ptCaseObj.adderror('You have passed the deadline to cancel this order in Salesforce.  Please reach out to your customer service desk at <a href="tel:555-555-5555" target="_blank">'+BST.Customer_Service_Number__c+'</a>',false);
```

It is working on desktop,  but not on Salesforce1.  Any help will be most appreciated.  Thx.

[image: desktop]

[image: salesforce1]

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005GoGIAU